# convert JSTL object to Java Object

Tags: java, jstl

I have one JSTL Object like 
`<c:set var="testOne" value="regst.firstName"/>`

i want to access the **testOne** jstl object in scriptlet scope as java object like

        `<%   String to = testOne; 
        %>`

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
String to = (String) request.getAttribute("testOne");
```